# Concatenate table without header

Tags: text-processing, cat

I would like to concatenate several tables and just keeping the header in the first line (and thus not having a new header each time that a new table has been concatenate). Does anyone know how to do that?

I am currently using:

```
find "/dir/folder" name "*.dat" -exec cat {} + >> "/dir/folder/table.txt"
```

but I can get rid of the header with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a BSD/GNU `sed`:

```sh
find "/dir/folder" -name "*.dat" -exec sed -se1d {} + >> "/dir/folder/table.txt"
```

...which instructs to treat all input files separately, and for each to `d`elete the `1`st line.

If the header isn't already in table.txt, you should first put it there, though:

```sh
set -- /dir/folder/*.dat
head -n1 <"$1" >>/dir/folder/table.txt
find ...
```

If all of the `*.dat` matches are in child directories, that won't work though.

```sh
{   find /dir/folder -name \*.dat -exec \
         sh -c 'head -n1 "$0"; kill "$PPID"' {} \;
    find /dir/folder -name \*.dat -exec sed -se1d {} +
}   >>/dir/folder/table.txt
```

That should.

Comment: This doesn't keep the first header as OP want.

Comment: @cuonglm, I was just putting that in.

Comment: That´s close to be ok, just the header is now gone! Even so I have put the 
    set -- /dir/folder/*.dat
    head -n1 <"$1" >>/dir/folder/table.txt
    find "/dir/folder" name "*.dat" -exec sed -se1d {} + >> "/dir/folder/table.txt"
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @steve - Nope, not really - it should work as long as there is at least one file which matches `*.dat` and the first of these contains your header on the first line in the folder `/dir/folder/`. If all if the `*.dat` files are in child directories, though, you'll need to glob one of those, I guess.

Comment: @steve - that edit should work.

Answer (score 2):

If the header is on one line, with GNU `tail`:

```
find "/dir/folder" -name "*.dat" -exec tail -qn +2 {} +
```

POSIXly, you'd need to run one `tail` per file:

To preserve the header of the first file, GNUly:

```
find "/dir/folder" -name "*.dat" -print0 | {
   IFS= read -rd '' first &&
     cat "$first" &&
     xargs -r0 tail -qn +2
}
```

Comment: I think I have been unclear because none of those answer work. In fact I have thousand of tables in several subfolder within a directory from the root directory I want to access those tables and create a new one grouping all the tables from the subfolder and just having one header in the first line. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: @steve, that solution outputs files starting at their second line. You can then append that to a file that already contains the header.

Answer (score 1):

If all your files can be fit in to one `awk` invocation:

```
find "/dir/folder" name "*.dat" -exec awk 'FNR == 1 && NR != 1 {next};1' {} +
```

Comment: It´s not really working. Could you learn me what´s the meaning of ['FNR == 1 && NR != 1 {next};1'] ?

Comment: @steve: Yes, like I said, it only works when all your files fit in one `awk` invocation. `FNR == 1` mean the first line of file, `NR != 1` mean we aren't at the first line of first file. `FNR == 1 && NR != 1` is true when we are at the first line of each files start at second one, if we are here, `next` skip that line.

Comment: Why downvote here?

Answer (score 0):

`tail` allow you to skip given number of lines:

```
find "/dir/folder" name "*.dat" -exec tail +2 {} + >> "/dir/folder/table.txt"
```

Comment: The `tail` implementations like GNU's that support passing more than one file argument generally also then output their own header to identify the files. [With GNU `tail`, you can use `-q` to prevent that.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219908)